# how to get data from online as well as offline and set in tableView swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i am working on a ApiApp , which get all data from api and set in tableView now i also set Realm to save that data in Realm database so when internet is not available it show offline data in tableView ,and when internet is On its also show , but the problem is how to set both values in one , for example when i set cell.textLabel.text = holidayApi.name it show online api data and when i set cell.textLabel.text = holidayRealm.name it shows me Realm data, now i want to set that when internet is not available it set to cell.textLabel.text = holidayRealm.name (realmArray.count) and when internet is available it set to cell.textLabel.text = holidayApi.name (apiArray.count) to get online data , can any help me any alternative or any solution

Comment: You should have _one_ data source (array) for your table view that contains either api or realm data. If the types are different you can create a protocol that matches the columns in the table view and let both types conform to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you know when internet is available and when not available. Lets say you have this information in variable **isInternetAvailable** then you can use this to populate the tableView accordingly.

For numberOfRowsInSection:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   if isInternetAvailable == true {
       return realmArray.count
   }
   else 
   {
      return apiArray.count
   } 
}
```

and cellForRowAt :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ....
    if isInternetAvailable == true {
        cell.textLabel.text = holidayRealm.name
    }
    else 
    {
       cell.textLabel.text = holidayApi.name
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Great, can you also upvote as this is useful.:-)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to save the data locally after fetching it from the API, you could always use the Realm data to populate the TableView and add an observer on the Realm Results to update the tableview as soon as the realm data gets updated (whenever internet is available).

Refer this -
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realm-notifications